# Using "latex" to externalize tikz graphics wont work

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdftex, shell-escape

I am lost in tex! I try to run a tay example, which you can find here: [EXAMPLE](http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-ii-external-tikz-library/)
If I run it, using

```
pdflatex -src -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape faster-latex-part2.tex
```

everything works fine, but if I use

```
latex -src -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape faster-latex-part2.tex
```

the following error occures:

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/mysphere" "\def\tikzexternalrealj
ob{faster-latex-part2}\input{faster-latex-part2}"' ========
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/mysphere" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{
faster-latex-part2}\input{faster-latex-part2}" ................etc pp
```

Do you have any idea what my fault is? I need to run it with "latex", because my original problem is a huge matlab2tikz-graphic in my thesis.

PS.: My system is a stock Kubuntu 12.11.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As you can read in, there is a given example (you can follow the link behind [link](http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-ii-external-tikz-library/)).
There you can find a whole project, where I applied the commands written in my post.

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem to me. Maybe you would be better off explaining what your problem with the “matlab2tikz-graphic” in your thesis is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Remarks

You weren't able to compile the version downloaded from the website using `latex`, because you can't embed `pdf` figures in a document compiled with pure `latex`. Here you need to fall back to `pdflatex`.

If you look it up in the [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) manual, there is a way to compile your externalized figures using `latex` and create a `ps` or `eps` file, which can then be embedded. Section 7.1.1 covers your problem.

## Implementation

I don't want to paste `mysphere.tikz` here, because it is a very longish file, only containing coordinates. Here is the original link, which is also given in the question: http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-ii-external-tikz-library/

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
%%%% From section 7.1.1 of the pgfplots manual
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi && ps2eps "\image".ps}}
%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \newlength\figureheight         % define length \figureheight
    \newlength\figurewidth          % define length \figurewidth
    \setlength\figureheight{6cm}    % set \figureheight
    \setlength\figurewidth{6cm}     % set \figurewidth
    \tikzsetnextfilename{mysphere}  % name next TikZ figure
    \input{mysphere.tikz}           % input TiKZ figure code
    \caption{A plot of a sphere}    % caption
    \label{fig:sphere}              % label
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

To compile everything, including building `ps` and `pdf` output, run `latexmk` with the following command line

```
latexmk -pdfps -e '$latex=q/latex --shell-escape %O %S/' faster-latex-part2
```

## Output

> [image: TikZ]